# Removing a downvoted question gives rep back when undeleting and when serial voting is reversed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, serial-voting

Today I received 3 downvotes by the same user in a timespan of 1 minute. I removed one of the questions because I agreed with the downvotes. This brought me to a total of -4 reputation. However when the voting was reversed, I received +6 rep.

[image]

I believe there's a reputation recalculation every now and then which I assume will address this but nevertheless it indicates something isn't working as intended in the back.

Comment: Now that is odd. Note for other readers that the first -2 is on a question, the unaccept is on the OP's *self-answer* to the same question, and the +2 for removal is for removing the entire question. The self-answer is not affected by the votes. This is why the +6 seems inconsistent with the previous day's history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Your question had two downvotes at the time you removed it. One of them was among the three serial downvotes that were invalidated.

The +2 from removing your question represents just that *other* downvote on your question. So it does add up after all.

Comment: Ah, sneaky. How come this wasn't shown in the history as a +4 rep gain when I deleted the question? It seems strange that it only addresses one of the upvotes instead of all two.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel: That's what I'm wondering. Probably something to do with the fact that the system outright deletes the votes altogether when invalidating.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It did. When the reversal happened, the +4 got reduced to +2 since that other vote got combined into a different event.